# Laravel - How to call model to class Helper then display the result in view

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel how to call model to class helper then display the result to view.

i have an error

> Non-static method App\Models\UserTypeHasModule::getModuleList() 
>       should not be called statically

Here's my code of that error

```
use \App\Models\UserTypeHasModule;

class UserRoleHelper
{
    public static function moduleList()
    {
        $generalSettings = UserTypeHasModule::getModuleList(1);

        return $generalSettings;
    }
```

Comment: The error is in your `UserTypeHasModule` model, `getModuleList()` is not defined as static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UserTypeHasModule` class the `getModuleList` function is not static and you try to call it statically, instead of making an instance of the class first.

So you can either change your function to:

```
public static function getModuleList( $id ) { ... }
```

Or make an instance of the module first and then call the method:

```
$generalSettings = (new UserTypeHasModule())->getModuleList(1);
```

Comment: It's Working... Thank you Very much